# Unable to import gTTS 'Unresolved Reference' in Python

Tags: python-3.x

Im using pycharm and trying to use Google Text to speech. When doing from gtts import gTTS, gTTS is not recognised, what am I doing wrong? I have installed gtts in pycharm.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same issue yesterday and after searching through different sites, I was able to get mine working.

First of all, you need to check if the module you installed is for use with the Python2 interpreter.
You will need to either run the script with python, or (preferably) install the module for use with Python3. Using pip3 should work.
Also be sure to have Pylint installed in the editor/IDE you are working with.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

like this you can add modules in your current library
you can run the codes first
pip install gTTS

then

you can run
pip install playsound

commands then restart your IDE by clicking file->restart ide option

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text